# Activar y desactivar la ubicación del navegador

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Sabrán si se puede desactivar mediante una función de Javascript la ubicación del navegador. Se que en Google Chrome se puede desactivar haciendo lo siguiente:

1. Ir a los ... (puntos verticales),
2. Configuración, mostrar configuración avanzada, privacidad,
3. Click en el botón configuración de contenido...
4. Ubicación -> escoger alguna de las opciones que ahí se muestran.

Lo que me gustaría es activar y desactivar la ubicación con una función Javascript que se ejecute al dar clic en un botón.

Comment: Hola, si necesitas la ubicación del usuario, puedes obtenerla sin el consentimiento. Hay varias opciones server-side, utilizando la IP del usuario; como esta API http://ipinfo.io/ que no requiere ninguna libreria, es solo un GET de http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La configuración sobre ubicación es una opción determinada por los usuarios, las páginas y aplicaciones web pueden obtener la ubicación sólo si el usuario lo consiente, por lo que **estas no pueden cambiar a su antojo esa decisión del usuario**. Es una medida de protección para que las páginas maliciosas no puedan rastrearnos sin nuestro consentimiento.

Lo que si que puedes solicitar el permiso para acceder a la ubicación si el usuario todavía no ha aceptado o declinado tu página. En caso de que la hubiese declinado anteriormente, puedes mostrarle un mensaje indicando como volver a conceder el permiso.

Para solicitar el permiso:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(funcionSiTodoVaBien, function(error){
// El segundo parámetro es la función de error
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            // El usuario denegó el permiso para la Geolocalización.
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            // La ubicación no está disponible.
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            // Se ha excedido el tiempo para obtener la ubicación.
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            // Un error desconocido.
            break;
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok, me parece bien, gracias Ramos-san.

Comment: ¿Y la ventana emergente que se muestra en los navegadores para permitir o bloquear la ubicacion se puede lanzar con javascript?

Comment: @AntonioPerez Si es la primera vez puedes hacerla aparecer ejecutando `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();`, pero si ya ha denegado la petición no volverá a solicitarla para la página actual.